# Why am I getting a linting error Unsafe call of an `any` typed value, when I have specified a type other than any?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, gatsby

This is my code from a gatsby-node.ts file:

```
interface IPage {
    path: string;
    component: typeof BlogTemplate | typeof PostTemplate;
    context: {
      slug?: string;
      limit: number;
      skip: number;
      isFirstPage: boolean;
      isLastPage: boolean;
      currentPage: number;
      totalPages: number;
    };
  }

  Array.from({ length: totalPages }).forEach((_, index) => {
    const currentPage = index + 1;
    const isFirstPage = index === 0;
    const isLastPage = currentPage === totalPages;

    createPage({
      path: isFirstPage ? '/blog' : `/blog/${currentPage}`,
      component: BlogTemplate,
      context: {
        limit: postsPerPage,
        skip: index * postsPerPage,
        isFirstPage,
        isLastPage,
        currentPage,
        totalPages,
      },
    } as IPage);
  });
```

I'm seeing that the error is pointing to the `createPage` call.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your other types/declarations too, especially createPage? Or create a mini-reproducible example - http://surl.li/iycpi

Comment: I'm not sure what's making it work now, but the linting error is fixed with no appreciable change to the code I've shared already or any other code for that matter.